# Handling canceled Paypal payments

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce, payment

I am currently using Paypal as a payment system on a website I'm working and so far everything works great...except one thing. Once the payment is complete, Paypal calls the IPN page I provided and everything's good. But if the person cancels the payment, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to know that since Paypal doesn't call the IPN in that case (at least, from what I understand).

Sure, if the person clicks on "Cancel and return to the website", he will come back to the Cancel page I provided. But what if he just closes the paypal page? He would never return to my website's cancel page.

In some cases, I guess it wouldn't be much of a problem. I'm sure there is a way to know if the payment is canceled but I just can't find it, which is why I'm here.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to implement some sort of confirmation field in your transaction table, eg: `ipn_confirmed`.

You set it to default as `unconfirmed` and set it as `confirmed` when paypal's IPN return the value. Then, you will only process request that is `confirmed`. If there is a glitch in the matrix, you will need your customer to contact you and send his/her paypal's transaction info and match is with your data. If it match, process it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I already have a field like this which is set to confirmed when I get the response from Paypal that the payment is complete, but I'm not sure how that helps me. 

Let's say I am selling an object and only one person can buy it. The way it works at the moment is that, when the person buys the object, it is reserved for him so that nobody else can buy it while he is completing his payment. Which is why I wanted to know if the payment is canceled, so I can cancel the "reservation".

Now I'm starting to think that might not be the best way to do it...

Comment: well then, you should make some sort of expiration time to complement the confirmation field. I'm not sure how long it should given the nature of CC. The main idea is, if this transaction is not completed during xx minutes / hours. The sales is opened again.

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it, what you just said makes perfect sense to me. Even better than immediately canceling the reservation. This way I could allow a certain amount of time for the person to complete his payment. Also, the person would have to complete that payment before being able to buy something else, or else people could just abuse of it and reserve a bunch of things without buying them.
Thanks a lot for your help.